# regular expression to fetch between start and end

Tags: regex

I am struggling to build a regular expression for the below issue.

Sample Text:

```
startABC)kasldstartXYZ,kjlksdstartMNO]aksdjfakstartDEF&#xA
startXYZ)kasldstartABC,kjlksdstartPQR]aksdjfakstartEFG&#xA
```

Output:

```
ABC,XYZ,MNO,DEF,XYZ,ABC,PQR,EFG
```

Start Word:

```
"start"
```

End Words:

```
"," or ")" or "=" or "&#xA" or "]" or """
```

Comment: is it the output is always 3 character after start?

Answer (score 1):

You are just looking for something like this:

`start(.*?)(?:&#xA|[,)=\]"])`

The text you want will be in the capture group. The closing delimiter is in a non-capturing group `(?: ... )`.

Comment: awesome mate, It was working very fine, But i need to exclude start work and end word, I need only middle part. Please help me.

Comment: The middle part is the capture group. I'm not sure how you access it in the language you are working with, though. Is there a collection of "matches"?

Answer (score 1):

Use [positive lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
(?<=start).*?(?=&#xA|[=,)"\]])
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sN2gZ2/1)

Explanation:

- `(?<=start)` Positive Lookbehind asserts that the match must be preceded by the string `start`.
- `.*?` shortest possible match of any character zero or more times.
- `(?=&#xA|[=,)"\]])` Positive lookahead asserts that the match must be followed by the chars which are  matched by the pattern inside the lookahead.

Comment: i think you need to escape the backslash one more time in nsregularexpressions.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:nsregularexpression] tag; it's used incorrectly more often than not, and it wouldn't really be significant anyway.  If you were writing the regex in the form of an Objective-C string literal (as the tag implies), you would have to escape both the backslash and the quotation mark, same as you would in a Java string literal.  But the *regex* syntax doesn't change; your regex will work in any flavor that supports lookbehinds.  Just FYI.